# optimize query over more than 200,000 records

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, query-optimization

I am working on a existing project, everything was working fine, but now the website contains more than 200,000 records. Now i got the problem of performance. Now when i try to fetch the records from the table it takes more than 20 minutes to fetch the records even if i have used pagination in my query. Below is my query to fetch the records from more than one table using left join.

```
    SELECT cus.sl_no, cus.customer_name, ccd.address, ccd.mobile_no, ccd.residence_no,
           ccd.office_no,id.customer_id,cid.manufacturer,cid.model,cid.model_year,
           cid.vin_no,cid.renewal_insurance_date,cid.insurance_company,
           cid.cr_no,cid.inhouse_outside,cid.sales_consultant_name,
           cid.sales_consultant_contact_no,cid.insurance_date,
           cid.vehicle_registration_no    
    FROM customer_insurance_details cid 
    LEFT JOIN call_allotment_ref_admin admin 
         ON cid.customer_id = admin.customer_id 
    LEFT JOIN customer as cus 
         ON cid.customer_id = cus.customer_id 
    LEFT JOIN customer_contact_details as ccd 
         ON cid.customer_id = ccd.customer_id 
    WHERE admin.alloted_date IS NULL 
      AND cid.manufacturer='"+mf+"' 
      AND cid.renewal_insurance_date = '"+mnth+"' 
    limit "+pageNo+",100
```

This query fetch the records from the customer, customer_insurance_details and customer_contact_details based on manufacturer and month in customer_insurance_details and 
joins the customer and customer_contact_details.

There is also a table call_allotment_ref_admin, in both table cutomer_insurance_details/call_allotment_ref_admin there is common customer_id, now when i run query the customer in call_allotment_ref_admin should not be visible in customer_insurance_details.

If there is an 101 customer_id in call_allotment_ref_admin as well ascustomer_insurance_details, then when i will fetch records this customer should not be visible.

This is an existing project, I am not allowed to add or remove any column in table, only i need to optimize query and make result fetching faster.

Please if you can provide me some information on this, I would be very thankful.

Customer

```
    sl_noint(10) NOT NULL
    customer_idvarchar(20) NOT NULL
    customer_namevarchar(100) NULL
    create_timedatetime NOT NULL
    last_update_timedatetime NOT NULL
```

Customer_contact_details

```
    sl_noint(10) NOT NULL
    customer_idvarchar(20) NOT NULL
    addressvarchar(400) NULL
    cityvarchar(50) NULL
    statevarchar(50) NULL
    pin_codevarchar(15) NULL
    countryvarchar(50) NULL
    emailvarchar(200) NULL
    mobile_novarchar(100) NULL
    residence_novarchar(100) NULL
    office_novarchar(100) NULL
    create_timedatetime NOT NULL
    last_update_timedatetime NOT NULL
    vehicle_classvarchar(50) NULL
    seating_capacityvarchar(50) NULL
    new_emailvarchar(100) NULL
    new_numbervarchar(50) NULL
    cubic_capacityvarchar(50) NULL
    special_conditionvarchar(200) NULL
    lastyear_premiumvarchar(50) NULL
```

Customer_insurance_details

```
    sl_noint(10) NOT NULL
    customer_idvarchar(20) NOT NULL
    vin_novarchar(50) NOT NULL
    insurance_datevarchar(30) NULL
    renewal_insurance_datevarchar(30) NULL
    insurance_companyvarchar(100) NULL
    service_adviser_idvarchar(100) NULL
    idv_novarchar(50) NULL
    premiumvarchar(50) NULL
    claim_bonusvarchar(50) NULL
    create_timedatetime NOT NULL
    last_update_timedatetime NOT NULL
    sales_consultant_namevarchar(100) NULL
    sales_consultant_contact_novarchar(50) NULL
    customer_typevarchar(50) NOT NULL
    vehicle_registration_novarchar(50) NULL
    manufacturervarchar(50) NULL
    modelvarchar(200) NULL
    model_yearvarchar(30) NULL
    cr_novarchar(50) NULL
    inhouse_outsidevarchar(50) NULL
    cover_note_novarchar(50) NULL
    variantvarchar(50) NULL
    call_statusvarchar(50) NULL
    service_advisor_namevarchar(70) NULL
    service_advisor_contact_novarchar(50) NULL
    accessories_typevarchar(50) NULL
    accessories_valuevarchar(50) NULL
```

call_allotment_ref_admin

```
    sl_noint(50) NOT NULL
    user_idvarchar(100) NULL
    permission_levelvarchar(50) NULL
    managerIdvarchar(100) NULL
    customer_idvarchar(100) NULL
    call_statusvarchar(70) NULL
    alloted_datedate NULL
    insurance_datevarchar(30) NULL
    customer_namevarchar(100) NULL
    addressvarchar(200) NULL
    mobile_novarchar(50) NULL
    residence_novarchar(50) NULL
    office_novarchar(50) NULL
    manufacturervarchar(70) NULL
    modelvarchar(200) NULL
    model_yearvarchar(30) NULL
    vin_novarchar(100) NULL
    insurance_companyvarchar(100) NULL
    cr_novarchar(100) NULL
    sales_consultant_namevarchar(100) NULL
    sales_consultant_contact_novarchar(50) NULL
    inhouse_outsidevarchar(50) NULL
    create_timedatetime NULL
    last_update_timedatetime NULL
    alloted_call_idvarchar(50) NULL
    ins_monthvarchar(50) NULL
```

Comment: Are there any indexes on your 'customer_insurance_details' table. If not are you allowed to create indexes?

Comment: No there is not any index created yet, yes i can create index

Comment: I have noticed, when i don't join customer and customer_contact_details, i got the results very fast.

Comment: Put an index on those joining columns,also why are they varchar?An int will work faster,assuming you have numbers in those columns.

Answer (score 2):

Using the guidelines listed below, you can create Indexes on your main tables which is 'customer_insurance_details' in this case. This should help you in reducing the run time of your query. As such your query is optimized in the sense that it is not using any aggregate function and directly fetching the columns based on few JOINS. So I feel Indexing is your only option.

- You should create indexes on columns that are used frequently in
  WHERE clauses.
- You should create indexes on columns that are used
  frequently to join tables.
- You should create indexes on columns that
  are used frequently in ORDER BY clauses.
- You should create indexes on
  columns that have few of the same values or unique values in the
  table.
- You should not create indexes on small tables (tables that use
  only a few blocks) because a full table scan may be faster than an
  indexed query.
- If possible, choose a primary key that orders the rows
  in the most appropriate order.
- If only one column of the concatenated
  index is used frequently in WHERE clauses, place that column first in
  the CREATE INDEX statement.
- If more than one column in a concatenated
  index is used frequently in WHERE clauses, place the most selective
  column first in the CREATE INDEX statement.

For syntactical information about creating indexes you can go through this Manual page:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp